# Group By With Complex Selector

Tags: c#, linq

I have classes that look like this:

```
public class Foo
{
    public List<Bar> Bars { get; set; }

    // Other properties
}

public class Bar
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

What I want to do is group `Foo` items based on matching names in their `Bar` lists.

Some examples:

- Foo1 with Bars { Bar1, Bar2 } & Foo2 with Bars { Bar1, Bar2 } => 2
  groups
- Foo1 with Bars { Bar1, Bar2 } & Foo2 with Bars { Bar2, Bar3 } => 3 groups
- Foo1 with Bars { Bar1, Bar2 } & Foo2 with Bars { Bar3, Bar4 } => 4 groups

(Note: There are also other properties in `Foo` that I would use in grouping.)

Comment: Not really clear what you're asking here. Could you show an example of input lists and expected output?

Comment: I know the key of the groups will be different `Bar.Name`, but what's your expected values of the groups?

Comment: Each member of a group will be a collection of `Foo` objects, with the matching `Bar` name as a key (or one of the keys).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1: Get all `Bar.Name`s, using `.SelectMany`.

```
foos.SelectMany(f => f.Bars.Select(b => b.Name))
```

Step 2: Group by the names in step 1, but now you have the names only, without the corresponding `Foo`, so in step 1 we need both `Bar.Name` and `Foo` as a new object.

The final query looks like:

```
var grouped = foos
    .SelectMany(f => f.Bars
        .Select(b => new { Name = b.Name, Foo = f }))
    .GroupBy(o => o.Name, o => o.Foo);
```

You can also use `.ToLookup` instead of `.GroupBy` in the last query step.